# Horizontal columns with multicolumn headers

Tags: html, css, css-multicolumn-layout

I have horizontal scrolling columns. There is some text with headers inside of them. I need to make each header forsing a new column and occupiing all space above columns beloning to it:

[image: Expected result]
or so:
[image: Alternative expected result]

But the best thing I can do is (by the way, it fails in Firefox):

[image: Actual result in Chrome]

I [tried to archive desired result using `inline-block`s](//stackoverflow.com/q/38598799/4928642), but the other problem occured there. I also tried some ways with negative margins, absolude positioning and `transform`, but with no success: they do not allow to get above columns (except `absolute` with conteiner context: it forgets column-based horizontal positioning).

Simpliest code https://jsfiddle.net/07n6L2yh/10/

```css
.container {
  outline: 1px dotted gray;
  height: 200px;
  -moz-column-width: 10em;
  column-width: 10em;
  -moz-column-fill: auto;
  column-fill: auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

h2 {
  break-before: column; /* Firefox? */
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  margin: 0 0 .25em;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu eirmod complectitur pri, agam libris euripidis no quo. In cum adolescens necessitatibus, et hinc nominati indoctum his, idque prompta moderatius cu per. Quo ei novum utroque, ius ex graecis volutpat quaerendum! Ea assum erroribus accommodare pri, simul omnesque scaevola has cu, an putant tacimates ius. Ius soluta nonumes ei? Ex modus eligendi repudiandae ius, nec cu quem delicatissimi.</p>

  <h2>AAA</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, explicabo.</p>

  <h2>Dolor sit</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu eirmod complectitur pri, agam libris euripidis no quo. In cum adolescens necessitatibus, et hinc nominati indoctum his, idque prompta moderatius cu per. Quo ei novum utroque, ius ex graecis volutpat quaerendum!</p>

  <h2>BBB</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>

  <h2>CCC</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
</div>
```

More complex version: https://jsfiddle.net/07n6L2yh/11/

PS: [Same question in russian.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/549065/178988)

Comment: I'd say each of those heading and paragraph sets needs their own wrapper.

Comment: @Paulie_D, yes, I tried with wrappers. Wrappers for group or wrappers for headers, or wrappers for both groups and headers. Moving headers in context of their wrappers or in context of container. But nothing helped. So I desided to post simpliest code to do not confuse readers with tons of wrappers.

Comment: @Paulie_D, https://jsfiddle.net/07n6L2yh/7/ for example.

Answer (score 5):

```css
.container {
  outline: 1px dotted red;
  height: 200px;
  min-width: 650px;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

h2 {
  break-before: column; /* Firefox? */
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  margin: 0 0 .25em;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  -moz-column-width: 7em;
  column-width: 7em;
  -moz-column-rule: fill;
  column-rule: fill;
  overflow-x: auto;
  display: block;
  font-size: 10px;
}
.each-sec{
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="each-sec">
<h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu eirmod complectitur pri, agam libris euripidis no quo. In cum adolescens necessitatibus, et hinc nominati indoctum his, idque prompta moderatius cu per. Quo ei novum utroque, ius ex graecis volutpat quaerendum! Ea assum erroribus accommodare pri, simul omnesque scaevola has cu, an putant tacimates ius.</p>
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="each-sec">
  <h2>AAA</h2>
  <div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, explicabo.</p>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="each-sec">
  <h2>Dolor sit</h2>
  <div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu eirmod complectitur pri, agam libris euripidis no quo. In cum adolescens necessitatibus, et hinc nominati indoctum his, idque prompta moderatius cu per. Quo ei novum utroque, ius ex graecis volutpat quaerendum!</p>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="each-sec">
<h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu eirmod complectitur pri, agam libris euripidis no quo. In cum adolescens necessitatibus, et hinc nominati indoctum his, idque prompta moderatius cu per. Quo ei novum utroque, ius ex graecis volutpat quaerendum! Ea assum erroribus accommodare pri, simul omnesque scaevola has cu, an putant tacimates ius.</p>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want all columns in same width add css to the class `each-div`

```
.each-sec{
  padding: 1em;
  flex: 1;
 }
```

Comment: 1. All blocks have different column widths. Is it possible to fix it? 2. If you open result on the whole page, text is equally distributed between columns and blocks have extra empty space.

Comment: _"If you want all columns in same width add css to the class each-div"_ - it causes all groups to have same width and single column. Height is ignored. I need different width of groups, but equal width of columns.

Comment: what do you mean by _equal width of columns_? columns of paragraph? or columns of the whole data?

Comment: Doubled text in first group in current version of your answer: http://i.stack.imgur.com/HORB4.png - height is overflowed, 3rd column didn't appear. Number of columns is fixed and not-dependent from content. Also second group has 2 columns when only one is enough.

Comment: Sorry, I've made a mistake with `column-fill: auto;` in the question. Updated it.

Answer (score 1):

Use this simple method

```css
.container {
  outline: 1px dotted gray;
  height: 200px;
  -moz-column-width: 10em;
  column-width: 10em;
  -moz-column-rule: fill;
  column-rule: fill;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

h2 {
  break-before: column; /* Firefox? */
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  margin: 0 0 .25em;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}
.left
{
min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
  <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu eirmod complectitur pri, agam libris euripidis no quo. In cum adolescens necessitatibus, et hinc nominati indoctum his, idque prompta moderatius cu per. Quo ei novum utroque, ius ex graecis volutpat quaerendum! Ea assum erroribus accommodare pri, simul omnesque scaevola has cu, an putant tacimates ius. Ius soluta nonumes ei? Ex modus eligendi repudiandae ius, nec cu quem delicatissimi.</p>
</div>
<div class="left">
  <h2>AAA</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, explicabo.</p>
</div>
  <h2>Dolor sit</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu eirmod complectitur pri, agam libris euripidis no quo. In cum adolescens necessitatibus, et hinc nominati indoctum his, idque prompta moderatius cu per. Quo ei novum utroque, ius ex graecis volutpat quaerendum!</p>
<div class="left">
  <h2>BBB</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
</div>
<div class="left">
  <h2>CCC</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p></div>
</div>
```

ethod

Comment: It soleves problem with column-breaking in firefox, but doesn't add vertical spacing to the header.

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid;
  
  white-space: nowrap;
  
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.article {  
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.article__title {
  font-size: 200%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

.article__body {
  -webkit-column-width: 10em;
     -moz-column-width: 10em;
          column-width: 10em;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="article">
    <h1 class="article__title">Title</h1>
    <div class="article__body">
      <p>SS Washingtonian was a cargo ship launched in 1913 by the Maryland Steel Company, one of eight sister ships for the American-Hawaiian Steamship Company and the largest</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="article">
    <h1 class="article__title">Title</h1>
    <div class="article__body">
      <p>SS Washingtonian was a cargo ship launched in 1913 by the Maryland Steel Company, one of eight sister ships for the American-Hawaiian Steamship Company and the largest cargo ship under American registry at the time. During the American occupation of Veracruz in April 1914, the ship was chartered by the Department of the Navy for service as a refrigerated supply ship for the U.S. fleet stationed off the Mexican coast cargo ship under American registry at the time. During the American occupation of Veracruz in April 1914, the ship was chartered by the Department of the Navy for service as a refrigerated supply ship for the U.S. fleet stationed off the Mexican coast..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="article">
    <h1 class="article__title">Title</h1>
    <div class="article__body">
      <p>SS Washingtonian was a cargo ship launched in 1913 by the Maryland Steel Company, one of eight sister ships for the American-Hawaiian Steamship Company and the largest cargo ship under American registry at the time. During the American occupation of Veracruz in April 1914, the ship was chartered by the Department of the Navy for service as a refrigerated supply ship for the U.S. fleet stationed off the Mexican coast.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Blocks have similar width.

Comment: Text is always equally distributed between constant number of columns. Height is not not limited. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/38598799/4928642 for more details.

Comment: Sorry, I've made a mistake with `column-fill: auto;` in the question. Updated it.